# Weberror at DownloadFile System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: c#

Whenever I'm downloading raw mp4 from the web and I keep getting this error:

```
Weberror at DownloadFile System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at ClipToTube.Web.DownloadFile(String url) in C:\Path\To\App\Web.cs:line 53
```

My code:

```
try
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36");

    string fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".mp4";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Functions.GetAppFolder() + "Clips", fileName);

    wc.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        return filePath;

    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    break;
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Weberror at DownloadFile {ex}");
}
```

Right after this I then get `Error: An unhandled exception caused mBackgroundWork to crash.`

Need help on why are they happening and how to solve them.

Comment: Is there access on that folder on the remote server? Does the files have read / write access?

Comment: No, the error happens when it tries to download them, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: But the exception reads *The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden* ?